# Where exactly do I put the source code header?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My professor wants our code to include a source code header and I don't know exactly where to put it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon May 22 21:31:16 2017

@author: noraasrar
"""
# Code starts here
```

The source code header looks like this:

```
###########################################################
#  Computer Project #5
#
#  Algorithm
#    prompt for an integer
#    input an integer
#    loop while not end-of-data
#       call function to count number of digits in integer
#       output the number of digits
#       prompt for an integer
#       input an integer
#    display closing message
###########################################################
```

Comment: Put it where your professor wants you to put it.

Comment: put it where you put the author ?

Answer (score 1):

The only real "restriction" to where you could put that is beneath the first two lines, the shebang and the line declaring the encoding. The first line helps your OS determine how to execute the file, and the second [tells the Python executable what file encoding to use when it reads the script](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Since the "source code header" is just a comment block, this'll probably work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon May 22 21:31:16 2017

@author: noraasrar
"""
###########################################################
#  Computer Project #5
#
#  Algorithm
#    prompt for an integer
#    input an integer
#    loop while not end-of-data
#       call function to count number of digits in integer
#       output the number of digits
#       prompt for an integer
#       input an integer
#    display closing message
###########################################################
# Code starts here
```